# why my <div> wont update?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

the application was originally intended to update "`div-list`" block in search and when passed valid product codes to search the **LINQ** returned a valid product but it did not load the partial page `_ProductCategoryList`. To test i have added `<p>updated</p>` in to js function `loadtodiv()` but it did not display that message either.Why this partial page or this html message wont get displayed on that div?

in my MVC4 razor app i have the an index page with the following razor syntax:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("GetCategory", "Home",
new AjaxOptions { 
    HttpMethod="GET", 
    UpdateTargetId="div-list",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    OnSuccess = "loadtodiv"
}))
{
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Code" value="" style="width:500px;" />
    <input type="Submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search" id="search-btn"/>
}

<br />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadtodiv() {
        $('#div-list').html('<p>updated</p>');
    }
</script>


<div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Index</h2>        


</div>
<div id="div-list">

<p>this is empty</p>    
</div>
```

the controller to the index page is :

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace eComm1.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            TUDBEntities _db = new TUDBEntities();

            //
            // GET: /Home/

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }

            public ActionResult GetCategory(string Code)
            {
                var categories = _db.mt_ProductCategories.Where(pc => pc.CatCode == Code).FirstOrDefault();
                return PartialView("_ProductCategoryList", categories);
            }
    }
}
```

and my partial view _ProductCategoryList.cshtml is :

```
@model IEnumerable<eComm1.Models.ProductCategory>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CategoryCode)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Url)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryCode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Url)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: You code would throw an exception. You passing a single `ProductCategory` (your use of `.FirstOrDefault()`) to a partial view which expects a collection.

Comment: @StephenMuecke no errors thrown so far except the partial wont display

Comment: Because internally your throwing an exception!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query in the `GetCategory()` method returns a single `ProductCategory` (the use of `.FirstOrDefault()` which you then pass to a partial view which expects `IEnumerable<ProductCategory>` resulting in an exception. And the `OnSuccess` function is never run because there is no success.

Change you query to return a collection

```
public ActionResult GetCategory(string Code)
{
    var categories = _db.mt_ProductCategories.Where(pc => pc.CatCode == Code);
    return PartialView("_ProductCategoryList", categories);
}
```

Comment: i have changed the FirstOrDefualt() to ToList() still the same problem

Comment: Then you have other problems as well. Start by just typing `../Home/GetCategory?code=someValue` in the address bar and see what is displayed

Comment: it has given me the following runtime error The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[eComm1.mt_ProductCategories]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[eComm1.Models.ProductCategory]'.

Comment: Then you need to change the view to `IEnumerable<eComm1.mt_ProductCategories>` (or you need to project the query to typeof `eComm1.Models.ProductCategory`)

Comment: thanks stephen problem solved, but i need to ask the second question how do i load the partial from my js function?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Your partial view is being loaded from the `Ajax.BeginForm()` method (but if you still have the `$('#div-list').html('<p>updated</p>');` line of code, then you immediately overwrite it.